# Exporting in-game data to csv in Unity

Tags: c#, csv, unity-game-engine, export

I would like to export my counter data with the time as csv file and then I will make a 2D graph with them. How can I record and write these on to a csv file ?

Comment: So what is the question exactly? How do I store 2D coordinates? How to a create a CSV content from a given set of 2D coordinates? Or How do I write to a file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is quite broad but today I'm in the mood ^^

As I understand you are actually asking the following:

> **How do I store counter values with a time value?**

I would use a proper type and [`List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) like e.g.

```
[Serializable]
public class KeyFrame
{
    public int Value;
    public float Time;

    public KeyFrame(){}

    public KeyFrame (int value, float time)
    {
        Value = value;
        Time = time;
    }
}

private List<KeyFrame> keyFrames = new List<KeyFrame>(10000);
```

Then I would make my counter a [Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)   every time the value is changed it tracks a new entry in the list

```
private int _counter;
public int Counter
{
    get => _counter;
    set
    {
        _counter = value;
        keyFrames.Add(new KeyFrame (value, Time.time));
    }
}
```

Now every time you do e.g.

```
Counter++;
```

a new entry with the current [`Time.time`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html)

> The time in seconds since the app was started.

is added to the list so you should additionally initialize it with `0`

```
private void Start ()
{
    Counter = 0;
}
```

---

> **How to a create a CSV content from a given set of 2D coordinates?**

```
public string ToCSV()
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder("Time,Value");
    foreach(var frame in keyFrames)
    {
        sb.Append('\n').Append(frame.Time.ToString()).Append(',').Append(frame.Value.ToString());
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

This creates a string like e.g.

```
Time,Value
0,0
2.288847,1
4.2887477,2
...
```

---

> **How do I write to a file?**

Usually you should write into [`Application.persistentDataPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) or in the Editor also the [`Application.streamingAssetsPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html)

You could e.g. use a [`StreamWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter)
or simply using [`File.WriteAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext)

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif

...

public void SaveToFile ()
{
    // Use the CSV generation from before
    var content = ToCSV();

    // The target file path e.g.
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    var folder = Application.streamingAssetsPath;

    if(! Directory.Exists(folder) Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
#else
    var folder = Application.persistentDataPath;
#endif

    var filePath = Path.Combine(folder, "export.csv");

    using(var writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, false))
    {
        writer.Write(content);
    }

    // Or just
    //File.WriteAllText(content);

    Debug.Log($"CSV file written to \"{filePath}\"");

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    AssetDatabase.Refresh();
#endif
}
```

Comment: That helped a lot thank you so much.

Comment: `sb.Append('/n')` this forward slash should be a backslash :)

Comment: @PremierBromanov that's true thanks ;) the same goes for the `/"` which should rather be `\"` ;)